# Imaginary number to some real power

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\omega > 0$ and $i^2 = -1$. Is the following true?

$$(-1)^\alpha (i\omega)^\alpha \stackrel{?}{=} (-i\omega)^\alpha$$

I thought I managed to proof it with writing these numbers using Euler's formula. But when I plot the difference in wolfram, it doesn't give 0 as a result. What is happening here?

Comment: The identities of exponents $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$ and $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ hold as equations when the bases of exponentiation are positive real numbers. They generally don't hold with negative or complex bases, unless you use a multivalued exponential function. Then the equations still hold, when understood as being about the entire set of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't actually define a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $x\mapsto(-1)^x.$ In fact, even if we want to define a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ by $x\mapsto(-1)^x,$ we can't do so uniquely, as we could viably say that $f(1/2)=i$ or that $f(1/2)=-i.$ Our choice of that value determines which specific *branch* of what we might call a "[multi-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function)" we're using.

As a result of subtleties and eccentricities like this, we cannot in general say that $(xy)^z=x^zy^z$ unless $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, without looking at things in a very different way.

Comment: Does the condition $f(1/2) = i$ determine that function uniquely? Or does one need to specify more values of $f$?

Comment: The value doesn't determine the function uniquely on its own. However, if we require that it be an [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), as exponential functions generally are, then we get uniqueness. Without something like that, we may have nothing like uniqueness--in fact, there are as many points in $\Bbb C$ as there are functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ satisfying $f(x)=(-1)^x$ (whatever that means) for all $x.$